# Angular e2e Fails at simple by.css expectation

Tags: protractor, angular7, e2e-testing, angularjs-e2e

I'm new to Angular and e2e. I'm trying to start with e2e default template that comes with Angular. I have made some little modifications to that trying to run. But some how my test fails at `by.Css`

Here is the `app.po.ts`

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {
  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get(browser.baseUrl) as Promise<any>;
  }

  getTitleText() {
    return element(by.css('h4.caption-title')).getText() as Promise<string>;
  }
}
```

Below is the HTML that I'm using,

```
<div class="news-caption">
   <h4 class="caption-title">App</h4>
</div>
```

Here is my `app.e2e-spec.ts`,

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { browser, logging } from 'protractor';

describe('workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();
  });

  it('should display app caption title', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect(page.getTitleText()).toEqual('App');
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    // Assert that there are no errors emitted from the browser
    const logs = await browser.manage().logs().get(logging.Type.BROWSER);
    expect(logs).not.toContain(jasmine.objectContaining({
      level: logging.Level.SEVERE,
    }));
  });
});
```

But the test always fails at this expectation step. Am I missing any thing or using wrong css selector?

Comment: Could you include what failure message you are seeing?

Comment: @DublinDev now its running and showing success message. Looks weird.

Comment: why do you define return type "as Promise<string>"? keep it on function level to be more correct.

Comment: @infern0 That is the default template I modified. I need to learn more and understand